# How can I share props (two-ways) between two components of the same type with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I'm building a music app using React, and I'm a newbie :)

My goal is to

- load a JSON playlist (formatted as [JSPF](https://www.xspf.org/jspf/))
- display a Playlist based on this JSON
- fill a Player's queue with the playlist tracks.

So I'm working on several components : Track, Tracklist, Playlist, and Player.

- Tracklists have Tracks.
- Playlist and Player have a Tracklist (and other things) : the Player's queue is a Tracklist component.
- Player is not a descendant of Playlist, it is aside.  For instance, I want to be able to queue (or unqueue) some tracks of the Playlist into the Player.

What I want is to be able to **share/sync the props** of a (same) Track between the Playlist and the Player :

Let's say that I have a *favorited* prop for a Track.
I would toggle it by clicking a button nested in the Track component.
I need to update the props of both tracks either if I click the button within the Playlist, or within the Player; and vice verca : all props should be "synced".

Can I do this with React and how ?

Thanks a lot for your advices !

Comment: Lift it up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

You should have a container component and other components (Track, Tracklist, Playlist, and Player) as children of container component, container component can pass props to children and refrence of functions as props, so can have all the logic.

You can check this exmaple:
https://github.com/upretim/thinking-in-react/

In this example all the components except App component are dumb/ functional component, App is smart/ stateful or container component, which has all the logic and data. In the example value of filter is shared between child components using parent component.

Comment: I plan to embed this in a Wordpress website : there would be the Player, and an iframe for the content (& thus playlists), so I could navigate without having the player interrupted.  So it cannot work like you said, can it ?